# Rails has_many through multiple alias for same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alias, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I have 3 Models. Archive -> ArchiveJoin <- Contacts

ArchiveJoin is a polymorphic join table. I want to be able to associate Archive and contacts through the join table and be able to query them using an alias.

For example a contact can be referenced as Author, Co-author, publisher etc.

My solution for this is on the archive table I reference the association like this.

```
    has_many :author, :through => :archive_joins, :source => :archiveable, :source_type => 'Contact'
    has_many :co_author, :through => :archive_joins, :source => :archiveable, :source_type => 'Contact'
    has_many :publisher, :through => :archive_joins, :source => :archiveable, :source_type => 'Contact'
```

The problem is that when I call any one of these I get the same contact rather then differentiating between there aliased names.

```
irb(main):082:0> Archive.first.author
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Contact id: 1, created_at: "2022-06-06 14:26:35", updated_at: "2022-06-06 14:26:35">, #<Contact id: 2, created_at: "2022-06-06 15:36:24", updated_at: "2022-06-06 15:36:24">]>

irb(main):083:0> Archive.first.co_author
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Contact id: 1, created_at: "2022-06-06 14:26:35", updated_at: "2022-06-06 14:26:35">, #<Contact id: 2, created_at: "2022-06-06 15:36:24", updated_at: "2022-06-06 15:36:24">]>

irb(main):084:0> Archive.first.publisher
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Contact id: 1, created_at: "2022-06-06 14:26:35", updated_at: "2022-06-06 14:26:35">, #<Contact id: 2, created_at: "2022-06-06 15:36:24", updated_at: "2022-06-06 15:36:24">]>
```

Is there any way to resolve through rails or would I have to create custom methods to differentiate? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you differentiate `Author, Co-author, publisher` in the contact table? Is there any column for that?

Comment: No there is no differentiating on the contact table between these different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done with Rails, but we need an extra column on ArchiveJoin table to indicate which kind of association it has. (Contact can stay the same so that one can be both Author, Co-author or Publisher without duplications).

Assume that we call the extra column "archive_join_type", we can do this:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :author_archive_joins, -> { where(archive_join_type: :author) }, class_name: "ArchiveJoin"
  has_many :coauthor_archive_joins, -> { where(archive_join_type: :coauthor) }, class_name: "ArchiveJoin"
  has_many :publisher_archive_joins, -> { where(archive_join_type: :publisher) }, class_name: "ArchiveJoin"

  has_many :author, through: :author_archive_joins, source: :archiveable, source_type: 'Contact'
  has_many :co_author, through: :coauthor_archive_joins, source: :archiveable, source_type: 'Contact'
  has_many :publisher, :through: :publisher_archive_joins, source: :archiveable, source_type: 'Contact'
end
```

Comment: Yes thank you for this snippet of code. Just to be clear I added this on the Archive model and worked perfectly. This is one of the ideas we were exploring. Adding a field on the join table to differentiate the what type of contact it is. 

First idea was adding it to the polymorphic join table and the second idea was creating a specific ArchiveContact join table. Both of these executions would still need a column that specifies its types. 

Thanks!